# Maximum size of trade respect to volume

Tags: trading, trading-volume

Is there a maximum trade size that you should keep under, in order to not screw up the market and ruin your trade? For example if on a given stock there are 10 million shares in volume, is there a maximum percentage of that amount that you should not exceed? What if after seeing that 10 million you place a 5 million order, meaning an order that equates to 50% of the total for example? In case you believe the price will go higer, and you place such a huge order, wouldn't that just help the price to go higher? If I buy more of a stock, the demand for that asset will go higher and thus its price, correct? If such maximum percentage exists, would that be related to the timeframe you are using in some way?

Answer (score 1):

If 10 million shares of a stock have traded, that's just a statistic for what has already happened at prices agreed on by counter parties in previous trades.  It has no bearing on how much price movement will occur if a new  order is placed.

It's kind of obvious that a 5 million share order will most likely cause share price to rise.  If we deal with something closer to reality...

If you place a buy order and it exceeds the volume available at the current NBBO quote AND no new orders come in to fill the balance of your order then the ask price will rise.  If your the size of your order is less than the current NBBO size then all you will accomplish is removing some liquidity and price will remain unchanged until either current auction participants change their bids and offers or new participants place orders looking for price improvement (the spread narrows).

As for what percentage of the daily volume will move the market, that depends on the size and depth of the orders on the order book.  And given that there are hidden orders, one can never truly know what that number is.

Comment: So the bottom line is that we should not care about this percentage, and just place orders as we want, even if they are hundreds of millions or billions in size. That's because the worst thing that can happen is encreasing the price if we are buying and decreasing it if are shorting, which by the way is exactly what we would want when trading.

Comment: If it's a must have position (buy or sell), you must pay/accept the prevailing price.  If you want a better price, you place a limit order which may or may not get filled.  Trading hundreds or thousands of  shares is no big deal.  If you get into the 10's or 100's of thousands of shares  range then it might require a different approach.  Perhaps you use an iceberg order (hidden order) to disguise your intent so that others don't pile on, driving price up.  And with size like millions of shares, it's a possibility that you use an investment bank to find a counter party with size.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean with this phrase: "so that others don't pile on, driving price up"?

Comment: Day traders are always on the look out for stocks where price is increasing on increased volume.  They want to get on for some of the ride.  IOW, they buy the stock,  aka they pile on.